# How to test a Solidity exceptions using Hardhat and Chai?

Tags: mocha.js, chai, solidity

I'm new working with Solidity. I have a very simple contract that is doing some validation

```
function withdraw(uint amount) external {
  uint balance = wallets[msg.sender];
  require(balance >= amount, "Pool: not enough balance");
  ....
```

and I want to test it so tried sometime like this

```
  try {
    await sut.connect(lp1).withdraw(utils.parseUnits("500000000000"))
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
```

but it's giving me the following error

> Uncaught RuntimeError: abort(Error: VM Exception while processing
> transaction: reverted with reason string 'Pool: not enough balance').
> Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.

It seems that my try/catch is not working. I tried expect(....).to.throw() but the result is the same.

It looks like something breaks at VM level and there is nothing to do from JS. I'm using Hardhat, Typescript and Chai.

Any idea? I was trying to find a solution but nothing show up... which is weird, testing these kind of situations is pretty common.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead. First install `ethereum-waffle` with your favorite package manager (`yarn` xD).

```js
import { solidity } from "ethereum-waffle";
import { use, expect } from "hardhat";

use(solidity);

describe("...", async () => {
 it("...", async () => {
  await expect(erc721.tokenURI(0)).to.be.revertedWith("ERC721: the token does not exist");
 });
}

`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, probably because I'm using *types/chai-as-promised*.

```
const withdraw = sut.connect(lp1).withdraw(utils.parseUnits("500"))
await expect(withdraw).eventually.to.rejectedWith(Error, "VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Pool: not enough balance'")
```

The trick is not waiting inside *expect*, and then using *eventually.to.rejectedWith*

Comment: Where 'Error' variable comes from? You put that within 'rejectedWith' function.

Comment: 'Error' is not a variable, is the "type" of the error